# Why Google still use my localisation when I have disabled all location services?

Tags: privacy, geolocation

When I use google.com (usually I work with duckduckgo instead, because of privacy policy) on my Phone **(in web browser)**, it shows me my city and country on the bottom of the page.

I have **disabled** everything in *Settings -> Location services*. What else do I have to do in order to disable any possibilities of sending my location to Google Search and other websites?

I Use Android 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *system setting* and the *browser setting* for location use different systems. When you disabled those settings in system settings, you disabled Google Apps (and other apps) from using your location, using your hardware.

However the browser differs in that while you use a webpage, the web server can use your IP address to locate you (using [IP-address-based geolocation](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-accuracy)). This does not have anything to do with system settings. The browser does not prompt you about this.  Indeed, once you connect to their servers, there is no way to prevent their servers doing IP-based geolocation, as their server can see your IP address and draw inferences about your location on its own.

Comment: I see. So the option is to disable them somewhere in browser settings? I've not confirmed any request for sharing localization on the website so far. I use the home wi-fi with dynamic IP and when I come to google.com from my PC (same wi-fi) it does not show the localization (I guess now that it's because of Firefox default settings).

Comment: Depending on the browsing app you use, you should be able to disable tracking under **Tools menu > Options > Privacy > Do Not Track**.

Answer (score 3):

Google has alerady taken your location, but if you go to another one, it won't change. Diagram here:

```
Location service | .|ON
Your current location --> Google
Location service |. |OFF
Your location at Google: [current location]
You move to another location
Your location at Google: [old location]
```

That happens because Google can't detect your location anymore.